# Haskell SQLite-Simple type error

Tags: sqlite, haskell, sqlite-simple

I am trying to run an example using sqlite-simple from [this Hackage page](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sqlite-simple-0.4.13.0/docs/Database-SQLite-Simple.html#g:13/%22this%20page%22):

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where
import Database.SQLite.Simple

main :: IO ()
main = do
  conn <- open "test.db"
  [[x]] <- query_ conn "select 2 + 2"
  print x
```

But I get this error:

```
Prelude> :load sqltest.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( sqltest.hs, interpreted )

sqltest.hs:9:12: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘query_’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Database.SQLite.Simple.FromField.FromField
                                  a0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Database.SQLite.Simple.FromField.FromField Integer
          -- Defined in ‘Database.SQLite.Simple.FromField’
        instance Database.SQLite.Simple.FromField.FromField a =>
                 Database.SQLite.Simple.FromField.FromField (Maybe a)
          -- Defined in ‘Database.SQLite.Simple.FromField’
        instance Database.SQLite.Simple.FromField.FromField Bool
          -- Defined in ‘Database.SQLite.Simple.FromField’
        ...plus five others
        ...plus 15 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: [[x]] <- query_ conn "select 2 + 2"
      In the expression:
        do { conn <- open "test.db";
             [[x]] <- query_ conn "select 2 + 2";
             print x }
      In an equation for ‘main’:
          main
            = do { conn <- open "test.db";
                   [[x]] <- query_ conn "select 2 + 2";
                   print x }

sqltest.hs:10:3: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘print’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include x :: a0 (bound at sqltest.hs:9:5)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show FormatError -- Defined in ‘Database.SQLite.Simple’
        ...plus 28 others
        ...plus 35 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: print x
      In the expression:
        do { conn <- open "test.db";
             [[x]] <- query_ conn "select 2 + 2";
             print x }
      In an equation for ‘main’:
          main
            = do { conn <- open "test.db";
                   [[x]] <- query_ conn "select 2 + 2";
                   print x }
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I installed sqlite-simple using Cabal. Then I tried to load the example code into GHCI. I am new to Haskell and am just trying simple examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `query` many types, therefore it's not clear what type `x` has. All GHC knows about `x` is that its an instance of `FromField` (due to `query_`) and an instance of `Show` (due to `print`).

You have to specify *which* type you want to query, e.g.

```
print (x :: Integer)
```

or

```
printInt :: Int -> IO ()
printInt = print

main = do
  …
  printInt x
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. But the next question... is the Hackage example incorrect? The largest issue here is that I assumed that the example code was definitely correct. Should I be more wary as I learn the language?

Comment: It's incorrect in the sense that the types are ambiguous. It's correct in the sense that the query works. I'm not sure whether that package is a canonical starting point to learn Haskell, though.